pip fails with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils' when running from python 3.12 or 3.13
I have several versions of Python installed (via apt). And when I run
$ python3.${version} -m pip

it displays the help message as expected when version ≤ 11. But it fails on 3.12 and 3.13:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/configuration.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import getLogger
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import get_major_minor_version
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/locations/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import _distutils, _sysconfig
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils.cmd import Command as DistutilsCommand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

I’m not even trying to install packages; I’m just dry-running the pip module. And no matter what arguments I pass to pip, it throws this exception.
I’ve read that Python doesn’t use distutils since 3.12, so why is it trying to call it?
Googling on the problem just leads to pages that suggest to pip-install setuptools but I’m not able to run pip at all.
Are there any library conflicts? Environment clashes? What can I do to use Python 3.12 and higher with the ability to install packages, rather than the bare distribution? I tried to reinstall Python — no good.
I’m using Ubuntu 22.04.1.

All your Pythons use shared /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ which they shouldn't because different versions of Python are too much incompatible to have a shared set of packages. This lead me to the conclusion that only one Python version should be installed using apt — default Python3. All other Pythons should be installed using other installers — conda, pyenv, asdf, pythonz (I use conda). So my advice is: purge all installed Pythons and install the default one using apt install python3.

Thank you. It’s time for me to learn conda.
